# Android Navigation Drawer & Fragment with swiping Tabs

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-activity, fragment

It is possible to have a Navigation Drawer and a FragmentActivity which has also swiping tabs?

E.g. When I select an item in the menu, a swiping tab view should appear.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question - yes, it is absolutely possible. [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) [Swipe Views](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)
Just follow above tutorials and combine them.

Comment: I already did this, but there occured several problems.

e.g. How can I pass a FragmentActivity Object to a FragmentManager?
That's what I need when I want to jump in the new Activity which holds the tabbed view.

Comment: FragmentManager is a component of every FragmentActivity. Can you further clarify your problem?